# Nokogiri XML and loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, loops, nokogiri

I made a script to get data from the indeed.com API. I get a response, but it returns every company name first and then every job title in one block.

What I get now:

```
ecutive KingswoodSales ExecutiveTrainee Van Sales ProfessionalJunior Broker (Opener) - Hong Kong - flights & accomodationTrainee Sales ExecutiveSales AssociateSales Executive
Mercedes-BenzMercedes-BenzMercedes-BenzSwinton GroupPorscheMercedes-BenzElite Sales RecruitmentImperial TobaccoThreeMercedes-Benz
```

I tried to add each do loop but it is blank now and I do not get an error.

My script:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

xmls = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=apikey&q=sales&l=&sort=&radius=40&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&co=uk&v=2')) 

xmls.each do |xml|    
  jobtitle = xml.search('jobtitle').text
  company  = xml.search('company').text

  puts jobtitle
  puts company 
end
```

My aim is to have my data like this:

```
Company 1
company name
company jobtitle

Company 2
company name
company jobtitle

Company 3
company name
company jobtitle 
...
```

This is the XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response version="2">
    <query>java</query>
    <location>austin, tx</location>
    <dupefilter>true</dupefilter>
    <highlight>false</highlight>
    <totalresults>547</totalresults>
    <start>1</start>
    <end>10</end>
    <radius>25</radius>
    <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
    <results>
        <result>
            <jobtitle>Java Developer</jobtitle>
            <company>XYZ Corp.</company>
            <city>Austin</city>
            <state>TX</state>
            <country>US</country>
            <formattedLocation>Austin, TX</formattedLocation>
            <source>Dice</source>
            <date>Mon, 02 Aug 2010 16:21:00 GMT</date>
            <snippet>looking for an object-oriented Java Developer... Java Servlets, HTML, JavaScript,
            AJAX, Struts, Struts2, JSF) desirable. Familiarity with Tomcat and the Java...</snippet>
            <url>http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=12345&indpubnum=8343699265155203</url>
            <onmousedown>indeed_clk(this,'0000');</onmousedown>
            <latitude>30.27127</latitude>
            <longitude>-97.74103</longitude>
            <jobkey>12345</jobkey>
            <sponsored>false</sponsored>
            <expired>false</expired>
            <formattedLocationFull>Austin, TX</formattedLocationFull>
            <formattedRelativeTime>11 hours ago</formattedRelativeTime>
        </result>
        ...
    </results>
</response>
```

Comment: I dont see any campanies name or jobtitle in the link you passed into Nokogiri Class

Comment: can you post an example xml?

Comment: Is the object coming back an array or is it exactly as you have shown above which is one big string?

Comment: @rob I added the xml sample in the above. thanks for you reply.

Comment: @BrianKunzig I do not get any logs errors from ruby, so i do not know. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the css selector for this.

```
xmls = Nokogiri::XML(open('......')) 

xmls.css('results result').each do |xml|
  jobtitle = xml.css('jobtitle').text
  company = xml.css('company').text
  puts jobtitle
  puts company 
end
```

Comment: Be careful using `xml.css('jobtitle').text` or `xml.css('company').text`. `css` will find all matching nodes and return a NodeSet. The result of using `text` on a NodeSet is usually _not_ what people want. Instead, use `xml.at('jobtitle').text` and `xml.at('company').text` to get the content of the first matching node.